# Expected distance of biased 1d random walk with 0 drift

Tags: probability, reference-request, gamma-function, random-walk

There were many question about biased 1d random walks earlier, but as far as I can tell none of these are directly related.

Let $p,q>0$ such that $p+q=1$. Let $X_0=0$ and

- $X_{i+1} = X_i+1$ with probability $p$
- $X_{i+1} = X_i-p/q$ with probability $q$

Note that $\mathbb E[X_n] = 0$ for all $n$. What is the expected distance from the origin, that is $\mathbb E[|X_n|]$? I am interested in the exact constant. One can calculate that
$$c\sqrt{n}\le E\left[|X_n|\right]\leq \mathbb E\left[(X_n)^2\right]^{1/2} = \sqrt{n (p/q)}$$
for some absolute constant $c$ (depending on $p$). Is the exact constant known? Note for $p=1/2$ the constant is $\sqrt{2/\pi}$, moreover we know the full Maclaurin series. What is known for arbitrary $p$?

Many thanks!

**Clarification about earlier questions**:

- The question [Random walk with zero drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285030/random-walk-with-zero-drift) is similar, however the direct calculation here already gives a sharper bound than the [Law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).

Comment: The number of steps to the right is binomial. The natural gaussian heuristics then suggests that $$\frac{E(|X_n|)}{\sqrt{n}}\to\sqrt{\frac{2p}{\pi q}}.$$

Comment: Great, thank you very much Did. I still do not have a proof, but knowing the right answer certainly helps a lot.

Comment: Actually,mentioning "heuristics" was being polite since one knows that $X_n/\sqrt{n}\to Z$ in distribution with $Z$ centered normal with variance $2p/(\pi q)$ hence the only missing step is to show that the convergence in $L^1$ holds. And to show that there are well established tools. Which ones do you know?